# How to split string to array while retaining its punctuation mark in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have this string:

```
This is,a good idea.
```

How to convert it to an array, and reserve its punctuation mark.
I know str_split and preg_split, but none of them can have the ',' and '.' mark in the array, what I needed is to have this marks in the array as an element.

Thank you !

Comment: what does your desired array structure look like?

Comment: Hi, I want it to be like array('This','is',',','a','good','idea','.')